# Load Jquery UI in Sharepoint 2013 Webpart

Tags: jquery-ui, sharepoint-2013, web-parts

I am attempting to add a simple datepicker to a webpart and am having difficulty loading the jquery UI css into the page I added the following to code to the webpart.ascx.

```
<SharePoint:CssLink ID="cssLink2" runat="server" DefaultUrl="C:\Users\mlamarca\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\CheckTracer\CheckTracer\Layouts\CheckTracer\Styles\jquery-ui.css" />
```

I am able to click on the text box and the calendar shows up but it does not have the CSS with it.

My document structure is as follows:

[image]

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are mapping it to your LOCAL Path, which is definitely NOT resolvable when loaded into your web page. Please use
**"/_layouts/15/CheckTracer/Styles/jquery-ui.css"** instead. (I'm referring to your screenshot on the Layouts folder.

Another way is to actually use this directly.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/15/xxx"/>
```